# Recursion With Array

Tags: arrays, c, recursion

Recently i was introduced into the concept of "Recursion" and it seemed fun untill i came upon an array in which  i was asked to get an array from a user with it's size and Get  the negative numbers and the odd numbers Count in the array , i have thought of some ways to do this but none worked , i tried making it with different conditions or loops but everytime i found myself resettings something either negative counter or odd counter or just an infinite loop , i can't seem to understand how passing an array through this recursive procedure works for some reason it keeps giving me wrong outputs so i resetted it and started all over with the base case , Is there like a general way to follow when making recursive functions ,  i know its about making your problem into smaller sub problems and creating the base case but i wasn't able to figure it out here , if anyone could guide me through it would be appreciate .

Down below is the code i made for getting the array and passing it to the recursive function with the conditions that worked with the iterative function , and tried putting the base case as `if (Count < 0)` because Count is the size of the array so i thought about starting with it and decreasing it by one everytime i want to call the function , but that didn't seem to work either , any ideas ?

**Thanks in advance !**

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int SortArray(int* Array, int Size, int* Negative, int* Odd)
{
    if (Size < 0)   
    {
        return;
    }
            if (Array[Size] % 2 == 1 || Array[Size] % 2 == -1)
            {
                return SortArray(*Array, Size - 1, *Negative, *Odd);
            }
            if (Array[Size] < 0)
            {

            }
}
int main()
{
    int Size;
    int Negative = 0;
    int Odd = 0;
    printf("Enter The Size Of The Array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &Size);
    int* Array = malloc(Size * sizeof(int));
    if (Array ==  NULL)
    {
        printf("Malloc Failure ! \n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Enter The Elements Of Your Array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &Array[i]);
    }
    SortArray(Array, Size,&Negative,&Odd);
    printf("Odd Count:%d \n", Odd);
    printf("Negative Count:%d \n", Negative);
    free(Array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have to count, first you should *initialize* or set to zero the counters and then *update* their values. Do you know how to change the value of a variable passed to a function as a pointer? Why this function has to be recursive? Note that you can always check the value of the *first* element of an array and then pass a pointer to the *next* element in the array (along with a size reduced by one).

Comment: it's gotta be recursive because the lecturer specified that in the question ;) , i do know how to change the value of a passed variable through a pointer , my question roamed about "how" should i base my conditions in the recursive function itself . My idea was to pass a pointer-to-integer that points to the counters i need and change ithe  values once my base condition is met , in my case it was if (Counter<0) but that was only an idea and i am trying to get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tried putting the base case as if (Count < 0) because Count is the
> size of the array so i thought about starting with it and decreasing
> it by one everytime i want to call the function

this is a good start and the function parameters are the right ones for what you want to accomplish. the name `SortArray` is a bit misleading, you are not *sorting* anything, you are *counting*, I think `Count` would be more appropriate. also `Size` is not really the *size*, but rather our "*index*":

```
void Count(int *Array, int Index, int *Negative, int *Odd)
```

the base case is right, we are scanning the array backwards, so when `Index` is less than `0` there is nothing more left.

now, you want to update **both** your counters **before** calling the `Count` function again. the update part is missing from your code, that is why you get wrong results.

I would do it this way:

```
int n = Array[Index];       /* current number */
if (n % 2 != 0)             /* is it odd? */
        *Odd += 1;          /* if so, update odd counter by one */
if (n < 0)                  /* is it negative? */
        *Negative += 1;     /* if so, update negative counter by one */
```

at the end we call the `Count` function again decreasing `Index` by one, as you already guessed:

```
Count(Array, Index - 1, Negative, Odd);
```

putting all together:

```
void Count(int *Array, int Index, int *Negative, int *Odd)
{
        if (Index < 0)
                return;

        int n = Array[Index];
        if (n % 2 != 0)
                *Odd += 1;
        if (n < 0)
                *Negative += 1;

        Count(Array, Index - 1, Negative, Odd);
}
```

the function should be called the first time with the *last* index and counters should be set to `0` (as you already did). from `main()` the first call would be:

```
int Negative = 0;
int Odd = 0;
Count(Array, Size - 1, &Negative, &Odd);
```

you could make a wrapper function to "hide" this (important) particulars.

Comment: This Is truely wonderful , thanks ! i was one step away from getting the right combination of steps my mistake was not updating my counters before calling the function i was updating them during the call and that what gave me errors , thanks again !